# How to call resource model method in model

Tags: overrides, model, magento-1, resource-model

I am overriding Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php in my local module:

#### Abc/Customer/Model/Customer.php

```
protected function _beforeSave()
    {
        parent::_beforeSave();
        echo get_class($this);   //Abc_Customer_Customer_Model_Customer_Customer is the above output

        Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer')->_beforeSave($this);
```

The above code is coming from Mage/Model/Resource/Customer.php

This is throwing an error :

> Fatal error: Call to protected method
>   Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer::_beforeSave() from context
>   'Abc_Customer_Model_Customer_Customer ....

How to call this method  `Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer')->_beforeSave($this);`

Comment: As per  as file location  `Abc/Customer/Model/Customer.php` class name should be  `Abc_Customer_Model_Customer.`plz put  config.xml rewrite code

Comment: Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer')->_beforeSave($this);

this is caling the method _beforeSave($customer) from 

app/code/Mage/Core/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php

Comment: i cannot understand your  question .There are few confusion on this why you have using ``Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer')->_beforeSave($this);` why you have rewrite  Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php

Comment: i am calling _saveBefore() , here am trying to post data external server, before posting the data to external server , we need to check weather the email used for registration already exsist in magento database.

Comment: If you are just looking for posting data to external server in case of a new customer registration , registering an observer on 'customer_register_success' event would be my best advice.

Comment: Hi Prateek, 
Yes you are correct we should 'customer_register_success'  trigger point for new customer.

Answer (score 1):

As the error already mentioned, you can't call a protected method outside of the class, but as the Magento system works, in this case, you don't have to.
Every model save call internally calls save method of it's resource model which in turn call the beforeSave method, that's the way models work in Magento, so the call you are trying to create is redundant in this case.

Also, I'd suggest working with the save_before events instead of overriding beforeSave method, they are much safer.

Comment: you are correct.  I tam trying with this solution , but looking for even best practise  of magento 

$this->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())->loadByEmail($this->getData('email'));

Comment: Didn't get that code part, can you elaborate ?

Comment: count($customerEmailCheck->getData()) 
 from the registration form , we will get the post data, we are checking here weather the email id is already exsisting in the magento database. If email id is found , through error and redirect the user to signup/registration  page, if the email id is not present push the data to ERP system as well as save the data in magento system, 

Note : in our scenario the data is getting pushed to ERP and saved but magento will throw error email id already exsist.

Comment: Is your registration form within the scope of Magento application ?

Comment: yes its in scope

Comment: Then, I'm pretty sure, Magento already checks whether email ID is already registered or not, why you are trying to do that on your own ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 'customer_register_success' as mentioned above by Prateek.

In _beforeSave() , customer model file i have used this one

```
$emailCheck= $this->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())->loadByEmail($this->getData('email'));
        if($emailCheck->getData('entity_id')!= ''){
//error message email id exsist
}
```